# array equality condition is returning more than the documents that match the equality: mongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a 3 simple documents in my mongodDB collection:

```
{
    _id: ObjectId('1'),
    item: 'test1',
    tags: [ 'red', 'blank' ]
  },
 {
    _id: ObjectId('2'),
    item: 'test2',
    tags: [ 1, 2, 3, [ 'red', 'blank' ] ]
  },
 {
    _id: ObjectId('3'),
    item: 'item3',
    tags: [ 1, 2, 3, [ [ 'red', 'blank' ] ] ]
  }
```

When I use this mongosh command (let us assume my collection is called collection in my database):

```
db.collection.find({tags: ['red', 'blank']})
```

it returns the first two of these documents. This query comes directly from mongoDB's documentation and it states: "[This] example queries for all documents where the field tags value is an array with exactly two elements, "red" and "blank", in the specified order". [source](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/query-arrays/)

however, in the second document my field '*tags*' does not evaluate to a value that "is an array with exactly two elements". This results in getting documents returned that are not exactly the value I queried for.

The third document will **not** be returned by the query I am using so it does not seem to search subarrays recursively.

Am I using the query wrong? If so, the documentation does not make sense by stating "...where the field tags value is an array with exactly two elements..." Or could this just be a possible bug, as according to their documentation it does not seem like this is what they want this query to return.

I can simply filter my results and obtain the information I want, my question pertains to if I am misunderstanding or using the query wrong.

I have also tried using this query in atlas with `{tags: ['red', 'blank']}` and it still returns the documents with _id 1 and 2 but not 3.

Comment: This seems indeed strange; however, you could add a [`$size`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/query/size/#mongodb-query-op.-size) operator to also query for the size of the array. This will still return false positives for documents with arrays as subelements and a matching number of other array elements, but will reduce the number of them.

Comment: yes if I structure the query with an `$and` operator and include the `$size` operator with a value of 2  it will work. But I just wanted to make sure that i'm not misunderstanding the query language. It is not supposed to return the second document, correct? my understanding of the query language is correct? if so, it must be some type of bug on mongoDBs end. Thank you for the suggestion on using `$size`! @Markus

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The third document will not be returned by the query I am using so mongoDB does not seem to search subarrays recursively.

This is correct.

---

Now let's understand why the behavior is as such, Mongo iterates over each item in the database array and evaluates them to see if they match the constraint.

From the MongoDB source code:

```
if (isArray) {
   // When the path we are comparing is a path to an array, the comparison is
   // considered true if it evaluates to true for the array itself or for any of the
   // array’s elements.

   result = make<PathComposeA>(make<PathTraverse>(result, PathTraverse::kSingleLevel),
       result);
}
```

This is how Mongo generates the comparison tree syntax, or as they refer to it "AST", as you can see by the comment the array has a special consideration that enables this behavior.

Essentially the comparison tree built by Mongo is trying to find a match for `['red', 'blank']`, it starts traversing the array in the DB.

For the document `{tags: ['red', 'blank']}`, the generated AST will traverse the tags field and compare it with the query array `['red', 'blank']`. Since the document's array contains the elements `['red', 'blank']` in the same order as the query array, the document will match the query.

For the document `{tags: [['red', 'blank']]}`, the generated AST will also traverse the tags field and compare it with the query array. In this case, the document's array `[x1, .., ['red', 'blank'], .., xn]` contains an inner array `['red', 'blank']`, which matches the query.

`[[['red', 'blank']]]` will not match as it will not hold under any constraint.

Comment: awesome! thank you so much for the amazing answer! I think mongoDBs phrasing in the quote I provided in my question is poor because it portrays that the query will not transverse the array and look at its elements!